# Python: Sum each lines with their values from dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
dict = {'A': 71.07884,
    'B': 110,
    'C': 103.14484,
    'D': 115.08864,
    'E': 129.11552,
    'F': 147.1766,
    'G': 57.05196,
    'H': 137.1412
    }


def search_replace(search, replacement, searchstring):
    p = re.compile(search)
    searchstring = p.sub(replacement, searchstring)
    return (searchstring)


def main():
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as filetoread:
    lines = filetoread.readlines()
    file = ""

    for i in range(len(lines)):
        file += lines[i]

    file = search_replace('(?<=[BC])', ' ', file)

    letterlist = re.split('\s+', file)

    for j in range(len(letterlist)):
        print(letterlist[j])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    import re
    main()
```

My program open a file and split the text of letters after B or C.

The file looks like:

```
ABHHFBFEACEGDGDACBGHFEDDCAFEBHGFEBCFHHHGBAHGBCAFEEAABCHHGFEEEAEAGHHCF
```

Now I want to sum each lines with their values from dict.

For example:

```
AB = 181.07884
HHFB = 531.4590000000001
```

And so on.

I dont know how to start. Thanks a lot for all your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already did most of the work! All you miss out is the sum for each substring.

As substrings can occur more often, I'll do the summation only once, and store the values for each substring encountered in a dict (and your above dict for the relation of letter to value I renamed to mydict in order to avoid keyword confustion):

```
snippets = {}
for snippet in letterlist:
    if snippet not in snippets:
        value = 0
        for s in snippet:
            value += mydict.get(s)
        snippets[snippet] = value
print(snippets)
```

That gives me an output of

```
{
'AB': 181.07884, 
'HHFB': 531.4590000000001, 
'FEAC': 450.5158, 
'EGDGDAC': 647.6204, 
'B': 110, 
'GHFEDDC': 803.8074, 
'AFEB': 457.37096, 
'HGFEB': 580.4852800000001, 
'C': 103.14484, 
'FHHHGB': 725.6521600000001, 
'AHGB': 375.272, 
'AFEEAAB': 728.64416, 
'HHGFEEEAEAGHHC': 1571.6099199999999, 
'F': 147.1766}
```

Comment: And can you please tell me how I only get snippets ​​between 500 and 1000?

Comment: just filter the output... e.g. `print([(k,v) for (k,v) in snippets.items() if v > 500 and v < 1000])`

Comment: I understand. Thanks a lot!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to simplify things...

Given you already have a string `s` and a dictionary `d`:

```
ctr = 0
temp = ''
for letter in s:
    ctr += d[letter]
    temp += letter
    if letter in 'BC':
        print(temp, ctr)
        ctr = 0
        temp = ''
```

In the case you supplied where:

```
s = "ABHHFBFEACEGDGDACBGHFEDDCAFEBHGFEBCFHHHGBAHGBCAFEEAABCHHGFEEEAEAGHHCF"
d = {'A': 71.07884,
'B': 110,
'C': 103.14484,
'D': 115.08864,
'E': 129.11552,
'F': 147.1766,
'G': 57.05196,
'H': 137.1412
}
```

You get the results (printed to terminal):

```
>>> ('AB', 181.07884)
('HHFB', 531.4590000000001)
('FEAC', 450.5158)
('EGDGDAC', 647.6204)
('B', 110)
('GHFEDDC', 803.8074)
('AFEB', 457.37096)
('HGFEB', 580.4852800000001)
('C', 103.14484)
('FHHHGB', 725.6521600000001)
('AHGB', 375.272)
('C', 103.14484)
('AFEEAAB', 728.64416)
('C', 103.14484)
('HHGFEEEAEAGHHC', 1571.6099199999999)
```

Answer (score 1):

Open you file and then read each character, then find the character on the dictionary and add the value to your total.

```
sum_ = 0
letters = "letters_file"
opened = open(letters, "r")
for row in opened:
    for char in row:
        sum_ += int(your_dictionary[char])

print(sum_)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.split` with `itertools.zip_longest` in a dict comprehension:

```
import re
from itertools import zip_longest
i = iter(re.split('([BC])', s))
{w: sum(d[c] for c in w)for p in zip_longest(i, i, fillvalue='') for w in (''.join(p),)}
```

This returns:

`{'AB': 181.07884, 'HHFB': 531.4590000000001, 'FEAC': 450.5158, 'EGDGDAC': 647.6204, 'B': 110, 'GHFEDDC': 803.8074, 'AFEB': 457.37096, 'HGFEB': 580.4852800000001, 'C': 103.14484, 'FHHHGB': 725.6521600000001, 'AHGB': 375.272, 'AFEEAAB': 728.64416, 'HHGFEEEAEAGHHC': 1571.6099199999999, 'F': 147.1766}`